# pytest applying fixtures to specific markers

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

Is it possible to only apply fixtures to tests marked with a custom marker? For instance given this:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def my_fixture
    # fancy fixture stuff
    pass

@pytest.mark.my_marker
def test_1()
    # tests something
    pass

def test_2()
    # tests something else
    pass
```

the fixture is only applied to `test_1`?

I have came across this question but what I am asking is the other way around! [Adding pytest markers to test depending on used fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63765233/adding-pytest-markers-to-test-depending-on-used-fixtures)

I have also come across this syntax but it is not exactly what I am looking for:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures(fixturename1, fixturename2, ...):
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something in your question...  `pytest` fixtures are only called or "applied" in tests where they are called and all tests run independently, so I'm not sure why you would need to do any marking.

Both of these tests pass and the `setup` is only called/applied once:

```
import pytest

class Foo:
    bar = -1

@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    Foo.bar = 10
    print('I was executed')

def test_1():
    assert Foo.bar == -1


def test_2(setup):
    assert Foo.bar == 10
```