# Select and/or deselect tests that use a particular fixture?

Tags: python, pytest

I see that there are some questions about conditionally *skipping* tests with certain fixtures: [Is there a way to skip a pytest fixture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46852934/2954547) and [Skip tests using a particular pytest fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70956586/2954547).

However I am looking for a straightforward way to *select or deselect* tests that use a particular fixture. I'd like to avoid manually marking all such tests, because the fixture might be used indirectly, and this is generally error-prone and not scalable.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to run something like `pytest -m 'not uses_foo'`, and all tests that require the `foo` fixture would be deselected.

Again, this question is not about *skipping* the tests. I am specifically asking about a way to make them (de-)selectable as one might normally be able to do with marks.

Comment: I think my question turned out to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/58492764/2954547, but it got a different answer so it was probably worth asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a builtin mechanism, but you can easily implement it yourself.

The [pytest_collection_modifyitems](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) hook is run after test collection, at which point all fixtures have been resolved. The names of all fixtures requested by a test can be retrieved via the `fixturenames` attribute. In the same hook, you can mark the tests with a `skip` marker or remove the tests you don't want to run entirely. If you want them to appear as `deselected`, you can call the `pytest_deselected` hook from this hook.

To make it configurable from the command line, you can use the [pytest_addoption](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption) hook.

Example conftest.py:

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--skip-fixtures", default=None)

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    skip_fixtures_opt = config.option.skip_fixtures
    if not skip_fixtures_opt:
        return

    skipped_fixtures = skip_fixtures_opt.split(",")
    selected = list(items)
    deselected = []

    for test_item in items:
        for fixture in skipped_fixtures:
            if fixture in test_item.fixturenames:
                selected.remove(test_item)
                deselected.append(test_item)

    items[:] = selected
    config.hook.pytest_deselected(items=deselected)
```

If you run `pytest --skip-fixtures "foo,bar"`, all tests using `foo` or `bar` will be deselected. If you want to skip them instead, add a skip marker via `test_item.add_marker(pytest.mark.skip("reason..."))`

Comment: I suppose this doesn't strictly answer the question because the tests are _skipped_ rather than _removed_. But you could just as easily remove the tests from `items`, right?

Comment: Likewise, it looks like you can _also_ use this technique to dynamically mark items with a custom mark `foo` and then deselect them using `-m 'not foo'`. Is that right?

Comment: @shadowtalker I changed the code to deselect the tests instead of skipping. If dynamically adding markers and using them with `-m` works depends on the order of hook execution. I haven't tried it. If you try it and it works, please add it as an answer so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks, maybe you can leave both versions (dynamically skipping and dynamically deselecting) in the answer. I found neither solution obvious from the docs, so putting them both on display here I think will be very useful to other people in the future.